# flib DLL load failed error in pymc under canopy

Tags: python, enthought

I'm using 64 bit Canopy 1.0.1 and like to use PyMC. I've installed PyMC 2.1b0 which is already in the packages but I get the following error when I call `import pymc` in Python:

```
----> import flib
DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

This module is not under the packages in Canopy. How can I solve the problem? Which DLL does it refer to?